# MongoDB: How to make a query that goes through an array

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I have a database filled with classes and I want to be able to find all of the classes that match the subject code and the course number provided.

```
course_number = ['2920', '3100', '3200', '3300', '3500', '4100', '4200', '4300', '4310', '4400', '4500']

for doc in db.all_classes.find(
        {"class_schedule.subject_code": "CSCI" },
        { "class_schedule.course_number": { '$elemMatch': { course_number } } } ):
    print doc
```

Comment: I think you need `db.all_classes.find(
        {"class_schedule.subject_code": "CSCI" ,"class_schedule.course_number": { '$in': course_number } } )`. Anyways try explain what the issue is and provide a sample document from your collection.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed!